# Community-wide meetup event

Tags: discussion, community, meetups

Does Stack Overflow organize community-wide meetups?

Like I'm mostly part of http://magento.stackexchange.com. So is there any kind of yearly meetup events? Where and when? How is it announced?

The same for other sites as well.

Comment: Why down Vote? Can ask right? Give reason behind please

Comment: some communities do but it's more set up by the community themselves and generally discussed on that site's Meta so not every site will have them. some are real life meets up like the Anime and Manga EU Meetup and some are online like [Arqade's Movie Nights](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11973/movie-night-october-2016). depending on how they are set up too depends on how you get notified

Comment: How community will decide & who will decide? Can i organize that? What are the steps to follow/guidelines?

Comment: no idea. my guess is that it's proposed on the Meta to see if people will participate then the steps are made actually run the event. depending on the kind of event and expenses involved the process will be different.

Comment: @Memor-X So there should be WiKi for each StackoverFlow Website Wise. Which everybody needs to follow for MeetUps. It should be Open & Accessible by All on Site Correct?

Comment: not really, like i said these are done by the community so there's no official way to do things. it's generally up to whoever is organizing the event and for the most part Stack Exchange doesn't support it (at least to my knowledge)

Comment: You get down votes because it seems to lack research. The related question list shows a couple of possible duplicates, where you didn't even mention one of those.

Comment: Thanks @rene for explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, SE doesn't organize community meetings themselves. Sometimes they do attend a conference about a specific subject, but the community isn't part of that.

Sometimes a community does organize a meeting, like Memor-X commented, Arqade and Manga do sometimes.

You are free to organize something yourself. There are no dedicated sites or pages to do this. You can use a chat room to find support for your meeting and maybe bring it up on the site meta in order to see if the community is interested in the idea. Don't expect too much from SE at this point, but if you have a solid plan you can always contact them using the *Contact Us* page to see if they have anything for yo to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks. Already sent info. Stackoverflow Community Meetups

Future Planning

1] Organize within Year (Site Wise/Overall)
2] It will be Online like WebCast/Meetups at One Place
3] If Meetups at Place. Find Sponsor.
4] Each community wise Take Moderators to Contribute Amount.
5] In Meetup @Place Ask for Speakers.
6] Who ever wanna join. There should be ticket with X amount.
7] Give small Freebies like T-Shirt, Brunch, Etc..

Comment: @AnkitShah How are you going to have a SE-wide event that will captivate *everyone's* interest? At best you can hope for people turn up to a more specific event

Answer (score 2):

To further complete the prior answer: you could also use what's called "Community promotion ads" on those SE sites that still / already use them. Such as the [currently active version of it on Drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516). Checkout this link (or find a similar one on an SE site you use) if you're not familiar with such ads, to understand the rules of the game, and also see some real world samples.

As per the nature of your question, I'd imagine such meetup-events would be an acceptable "topic", if posted on the meta site related to the SE site these events related to.

**Bottomline**: Why wait for somebody else, if you can do (organize) it yourself? ... Even using available SE infrastructure ... for free!

Comment: Probably the company itself would not represent, so there would be still no way to get the "Not a Robot" badge.